# javassist not working with spring boot jar

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, spring-data-jpa, javassist

I have a spring boot application with gradle which uses following dependency

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
```

This dependency includes javassist-3.21.0-GA.jar in the library.
When I run the application in STS IDE using run as springboot application, everything works fine.
But when I run the spring boot jar of application using command 
`java -jar <application-jar>`
then javassist throws following exception

```
javassist.NotFoundException: <class name>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Javassist only looks up classes from the class path. But Spring Boot uses its own class loader hierarchy when bundling it in a self-executable. You need to register this class loader manually for this reason. Have a look at [*ClassPool#appendClassPath* on how to include additional class path elements](http://www.javassist.org/html/javassist/ClassPool.html#appendClassPath%28javassist.ClassPath%29). You require to include your classes *ClassLoader* in a *LoaderClassPath*.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform bytecode analysis on springboot user classes then only way is to extract the springboot jar and add each and every class to the classPath so that javassist can perform bytecode analysis on it.

Answer (score -1):

You need this!!!

```
ClassPool classPool = ClassPool.getDefault();
classPool.appendClassPath(new LoaderClassPath(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
```

https://www.kagura.me/dev/20190923102501.html